# How can I open an URL address from a file using firefox in an Unix/Linux console?

Tags: bash, shell, file, url, firefox

well, I have a file with a url named "file.txt" that contains an url I want to open this url using firefox. I tried using `cat file.txt | firefox` but it doesn't work.
if you can help. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat file.txt | while read ; do firefox "$REPLY" ; done
```

Pass the url in parameter.

Or you may use

```
firefox `cat file.txt`
```

as a simpler version.